# Помогите составить маску для парсинга даты

Tags: java, дата, datetime

Есть дата: "Thu Apr 08 12:37:49 MSK 2021", у меня есть парсер на Java. Он нормально отрабатывает со многими комбинациями. Но вот эту не берёт, скорее всего из-за того, что я не корректно составляю маску. В принципе мне хватит маски до MSK - не включая MSK. По сути надо выцепить время (и разложить всю дату).

Comment: Отбрось день недели и зону. Остальное нормально отпарсится.

Comment: да, так и сделал, вообще просто время как кусок строки выдернул и всё. Просто стало интересно как это зад**цу разрешить можно)

Comment: День недели отбрасывается по-любому - его можно использовать только для контроля правильности парсинга, эдакий бит чётности... А зону надо или выбросить, или переместить в конец, вернее, переместить год на положенное место (уж не знаю, какое альтернативно мыслящее существо сунуло год в самый конец, когда ему место перед компонентой времени).

Comment: А существо это распечатка new Date.toString();

Comment: Если верить [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) (а ей обычно можно верить), то "присваивает .. значение вроде Mon Sep 28 1998 14:36:22 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)". Так что если ВЫ получаете кривое значение, то это где-то перестроено шаловливыми ручками...

Comment: Да вроде не лазил, я конечно на проекте работаю, мало ли кто там до меня чего крутил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так попробуйте `E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`. используйте [java date format](https://www.journaldev.com/17899/java-simpledateformat-java-date-format)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String dateString = "Thu Apr 08 12:37:49 MSK 2021";
    String pattern = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new Locale("en", "US"));

    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(date);
  }
```

Ну у меня в ответе

`Thu Apr 08 14:37:49 UZT 2021` - думаю понятно почему `UZT`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Apr 08 12:37:49 MSK 2021"
тупо Ваш код скопировал. То-то у меня не получается. Ерунда какая-то

Comment: Как думаете в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: хм хороший вопрос

Comment: может нет нужной локали? Попробуйте сменить

Comment: Винда у меня EN к сведению

Comment: попробую, спасибо!

Comment: @Saul и про галочку не забывайте если помогло